# WCF Error - unexpected response: (400) Bad Request

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-config, azure

I'm having trouble finding an answer for this problem.  Most similar posts lean seem to be fixed by adjusting some of the maximum size settings in the web.config file.  However, none of those suggestions have fixed my issue.

To give a little more background, I'm porting a asmx web service, to a WCF web service hosted in Windows Azure.  This problem came up during testing.  If I pass a small number of transactions to my webservice in a single call, it tends to work just fine.  This error come up though when my transaction size gets around 50-60 (transactions).  Serialized to xml, the file size is around 300K, so it's nothing insanely large.  But it does tend to lean towards a size issue.

Also, turning on WCF tracing, I found the following exception occuring:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowHttpProtocolException(String message, HttpStatusCode statusCode, String statusDescription)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowMaxReceivedMessageSizeExceeded()
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception&amp;amp; requestException)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)

So from the exception, it looks as though one of the settings if off in my web.config, but here is what that looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="MetadataEnabled">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
          <add scheme="http" port="8081"/>
          <add scheme="https" port="444"/>
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="111024000"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="Bandicoot.Core" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataEnabled">
    <endpoint name="HttpEndpoint"
              address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="wsHttp"
              contract="Bandicoot.CORE.IRepricer" />
    <endpoint name="HttpMetadata"
              address="contract"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="mexBinding"
              contract="Bandicoot.CORE.Stack" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Core"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="111024000" 
             messageEncoding="Text" maxBufferPoolSize="111024000" 
             textEncoding="UTF-8">
      <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="111024000"
                    maxArrayLength="111024000"
                    maxStringContentLength="111024000"/>
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
  <mexHttpBinding>
    <binding name="mexBinding"/>
  </mexHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions, or is there something mis-configured in my web.config that  I'm just not seeing?

Thanks for any advice!

Edit:  Here is the settings from my client's app.config

```
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_CORE" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="14194304" maxBufferPoolSize="14194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="14194304"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="1000" maxStringContentLength="111024000"
            maxArrayLength="111024000" maxBytesPerRead="1024000" maxNameTableCharCount="111024000" />
        <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Edit: adding addition client information:

```
        <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:92/CORE.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_CORE" contract="Core.CORE"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_CORE" />
    </client>
```

Edit: Attempted changing the service bindings to basicHttpBinding - config changes:

```
      <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="111024000"
             messageEncoding="Text" maxBufferPoolSize="111024000"
             textEncoding="UTF-8">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="111024000" maxBytesPerRead="111024000" maxStringContentLength="111024000"/>
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

      <service name="Bandicoot.Core" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataEnabled">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"
              contract="Bandicoot.CORE.IRepricer" />
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="mexBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Core"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

And the client's app.config as well for reference:

```
        <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_CORE" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="100000000"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:92/CORE.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_CORE" contract="Core.CORE"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_CORE" />
    </client>
```

Comment: and is your client endpoint actually **using** those settings??

Comment: Your service defines a `wsHttpBinding` - your client has settings for `basicHttpBinding` ..... are those even matched up?? Also - you didn't show us the `<client>...</client>` section of your client's config - that would be most interesting !!

Comment: @marc_s -  The majority of this client configuration was just auto-generated by the "Add Service Reference" feature in Visual Studio.  Since our customer's are going to consume this web service, It would be preferable if they did not need to hack up a configuration file for our service to work...  That's probably another question in it's own, so for now I just want to get it to work.   I've posted the client section of my config file.  Please let me know if you see anything that looks incorrect.  Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to confirm what binding is actually being used server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this one out this morning.  The problem was that my service was not using the configuration settings that I thought it was.  The reason?  The service name in the configuration needs to be a fully qualified path to the service being implemented.

I found this [link](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/191589/442381.aspx) helpful figuring it out.

I found it a little odd that my service worked without pointing it to an actual endpoint, I guess it just uses a series of default values and if you want something different you can configure them in the web.config?  I think this explains why I was getting a basicHttpBinding when I consumed the webservice in my client, instead of wsHttpBinding.

Took a few days to figure it out, but was educational.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You need to be setting the `maxReceivedMessageSize` **on the client** (where the message you're returning from your service is incoming) - in its `app.config` or `web.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="111024000" 
             messageEncoding="Text" maxBufferPoolSize="111024000" 
             textEncoding="UTF-8">
      <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="111024000"
                    maxArrayLength="111024000"
                    maxStringContentLength="111024000"/>
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
  <mexHttpBinding>
    <binding name="mexBinding"/>
  </mexHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client name="whatever">
    <endpoint name="HttpEndpoint"
        address=""
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="wsHttp"
        contract="Bandicoot.CORE.IRepricer" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The default value for `maxReceivedMessageSize` is 64K, unless you change it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't include my client configuration, I did have this setting on there as well.  I updated the original question with my app.config settings as well.

Comment: As @marc_s pointed out above, it doesn't appear that the client is using those settings.  The error message clearly shows that the current limit is 64K.

Comment: I updated the original post with the client configuration.  Would love some additional advice.

Comment: @Brosto: as I expected - the service defines a **wsHttpBinding** while the client uses **basicHttpBinding** - that's not the same!! You need to make this line up! Did you update the service (to use wsHttp) and then you didn't update the client after that, or something like that??

Comment: No, the service has always had a wsHttpBinding, but the client auto-generates a basicHttpBinding for some reason.  I did try making these the same by manually changing the client to wsHttpBinding, but it didn't work.  Let me try changing the server to basicHttpBinding and see if that has any impact.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and the cause was revealed to be a configuration error, too.

But in my case this was, like marc_s already posted, the **maxReceivedMessageSize** setting on the **server side**. The server was still using its default configuration, which was as low as 64 kb.

As obvious as this now sounds, that long it took me to find out that the error was not on my (client) side.

I hope that this may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Question Poster "Brosto"!

**This supplements your Nov 17 '10 at 15:29 answer.**

We had a “fun”, or should I say “educational” Production Deployment Testing issue today that took most of the day to resolve, and it was literally caused by one keystroke.  We only confirmed the source of the problem, after we found out the problem disappeared after the Web Farm was fully deployed.

Here was the cause.  When we test our Production Deployment, and do so against a **“Single Server”** by changing our hosts file, we are bypassing the Load Balancer, and the call to the Single Server ends up going over the default http port **80**!  When we test against the **“Load Balancer”**, the call to the Single Server from the Load Balancer, ends up going over the Load Balancer defined port **81**!

Since the **Service Endpoint Address must be “fully qualified”, to enable the service to find its Custom Bindings**, the Services.config file on the Single Server must be changed to reflect the difference between “Single Server” vs “Load Balanced Server” endpoint connections, as follows:

**Single Server connection:**

```
endpoint address="http://www.myserver.com:80/Services/MyService.svc"
```

**Load Balanced Server connection:**

```
endpoint address="http://www.myserver.com:81/Services/MyService.svc"
```

My boss correctly diagnosed the core problem early, saying that the server was acting like the **custom bindings were being ignored** and the defaults were being used instead. **After showing him your comment** above where you mention the **requirement of “fully qualified” service endpoint address**, he realized that the host file redirection was causing our browser request to go to the Single Server over default port 80, instead of the Load Balanced port 81, which in effect altered the fully qualified service endpoint address, which **caused the server to ignore the custom bindings** and revert to default settings.  **Please note that it did NOT fail to call the service, it only failed to bind the custom bindings!**

**Hopefully someone will remember this posting the next time we Production Test a Service with custom bindings :)**